# SQL Server fulltext search issue

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am working with SQL Server full text search. The issue is SQL Server is returning the wrong records.

For example: I am searching for `was` word in article's table column `striptitle`

```
SELECT
    TitleStripped  
FROM
    [pastic_com].[dbo].[Psa_Articles]  
WHERE
    FREETEXT (TitleStripped, 'was')
```

With this query, I found 8 records; for reference two of them are pasted below:

1. Seasonal dynamics and relative abundance of AM fungi in rhizosphere of rice (Oryza sativa L. cv. Basmati supper).
2. Seasonal dynamics of AM fungi in sugarcane (Saccharum officinarum L.CV.SPF-213) in relation to red rot (Colletotrichum falcatum) disease from Punjab, Pakistan.

You will notice title column does not contain "was" word .

For more reference here's a screenshot:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0gdI.png

Answer (score 0):

The [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) depends on [thesaurus files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-thesaurus-files-for-full-text-search) and [stoplist objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search). Please double check your configuration for entries related to `was`.

Also, note the difference between [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql) and [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql). If you look for exact matches of the word `was` then try `CONTAINS` instead of `FREETEXT` for the reason below.

Snippet from the documentation for `FREETEXT`, you probably want to avoid these actions.

> Is a predicate used in the Transact-SQL WHERE clause of a Transact-SQL
> SELECT statement to perform a SQL Server full-text search on full-text
> indexed columns containing character-based data types. **This predicate
> searches for values that match the meaning and not just the exact
> wording of the words in the search condition.** When FREETEXT is used,
> the full-text query engine internally performs the following actions
> on the freetext_string, assigns each term a weight, and then finds the
> matches:
>
> - Separates the string into individual words based on word boundaries
>   (word-breaking).
> - **Generates inflectional forms of the words (stemming).**
> - **Identifies a list of expansions or replacements for the terms based on
>   matches in the thesaurus.**